# How to split all multi-valued columns into several columns at once in OpenRefine using GREL

Tags: openrefine, grel

So, I have a complex XML imported into OpenRefine and merged all rows of all records to one using a GREL formula in "All => Transform". Now I have around 50 columns with each containing multiple values in each cell seperated by "|" and I want to have them in different columns.

[See here for two example columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5hiw.png)

I could apply "Edit column => Split into several columns" for each column but this would mean to do it over and over again. I am pretty sure this can be done via "All => Transform" using GREL but I haven't found a solution yet.
Please help me!

Comment: You have lots of repeats there too. So you'll end up with 50 times what columns, many with the same data in them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

My question already has been answered insofar as that OpenRefine (at the moment) is not able to split several columns at once. A workaround is just to "Extract..." the respective JSON code for a one-column-split from "Undo/Redo" and paste it to "Apply..." as many times as there are columns replacing the "columnName" in every pasted copy of the JSON with the one needed.
See https://groups.google.com/g/openrefine/c/BMoK35CCXYo